# Rubbersheeting in GRASS?

Tags: coordinate-system, grass-gis, vector, rubbersheeting

We are in the process of getting our property boundaries corrected and a side effect of this is that we need to move any assets that have been drawn relative to the property boundaries, so they are still inline correctly.

The company that does the property corrections gives us shift vectors and we normally run all our layers though FME using the vectors to correct the locations.

I was wondering if there is anything like this in GRASS?

Answer (score 8):

In GRASS you can use [v.transform](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/html64_user/v.transform.html) for this on vector data: Performs an affine transformation (shift, scale and rotate, or GPCs) on vector map.

Comment: Isn't an affline transformation a uniform shift?  I believe rubber sheeting is more of a distortion based on a number of different vectors.

Comment: In GRASS 7 there is now also a new tool v.rectify: v.rectify uses control points to calculate a 2D or 3D transformation matrix based on a first, second, or third order polynomial (http://grass.osgeo.org/manuals/html70_user/v.rectify.html)

Comment: Maybe also possible to do this with two linear reference systems? https://grass.osgeo.org/grass79/manuals/lrs.html