# Seeking Conflation tool for QGIS?

Tags: qgis, software-recommendations, conflation

Is there a tool to do conflation in QGIS?

ArcMap has a tool but I need to use QGIS. http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/editing/an-overview-of-the-conflation-toolset.htm

Comment: In its current form I think this is a duplicate of http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8262/seeking-open-source-tool-for-point-node-conflation-matching.  However, since both talk about QGIS and both talk about OpenJump, why don't you [edit] this one to be specifically about QGIS, then I can edit the other one to be specifically about OpenJump?

Comment: Have a look at this post, it may help: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4230/rubber-sheeting-in-grass-or-qgis

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is now a plugin call Vector Bender: https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/VectorBender/

This will give you a solution for rubbersheeting.

For the edgematching, the topology checker plugin should offer a solution, but may invovle extra processing compared to ArcGIS.  The plugin will at least flag areas that violate your topology rules and then you may need to manually adjust these areas.  There isn't a direct replacement for the edgematching in ArcGIS:  http://docs.qgis.org/2.0/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_topology_checker.html