# Polyline transformation in QGIS

Tags: qgis, line

I want to do following transformations to my land use poly line. Is there any way to do this process in QGIS? I have tried v.clean tool in QGIS, but it is not working properly.
[image]

Comment: What are the options you used in the `v.clean` tool ? What is the coordinate system of your line layer ? Can you give WKT on a sample of lines to "process" ?

Comment: v.clean--> input featur type:line, cleaning tool: break, snap, rmline thrshold:0,1,1
coordinate system:UTM32

Comment: what is WKT?  do you need a sample polyl line layer?
if yes, how can i upload my shape file here ?

Comment: You can edit your question to add details. For WKT : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text_representation_of_geometry. It's a geometry as a text format so you can paste it here. The entire shapefile is not needed, just some cases to try.

Comment: i have converted my lines as csv format and i think i have selected geometry type as wkt format. how can i add this here

Comment: At the bottom of the question post, below the `qgis` tag, you have links : "Share" / "Edit" / "Follow" ..., click on **Edit**.

Comment: There are 2 possibilities in this older question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/206595/seeking-conflation-tool-for-qgis  you're looking for conflation tools.

Comment: I suggest you ask for each feature in a different thread

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this is using [the Topology Checker plugin](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/core_plugins/plugins_topology_checker.html). First define rules, such as `near` or `coincide` for example, then the plugin would either correct them or show you where a problem is found. An elaborate instruction exists on the webpage that I've attached.